# How to structure a Continuous Music Streaming Ruby on Rails application? Websockets? Pagination?

Tags: ruby, pagination, websocket, streaming, continuous

I'm really ambitious about launching a RoR application which allows continuous music streaming. By continuous I mean uninterrupted playback during page changes. Whether I use jPlayer or I build my own is irrelevant to me. I am interested in the structure as I am just beginning to build the app. As far as my research goes the logical ways are:

Pagination (with ajax) and Web-sockets

1. Pagination. What I ultimately would want is to wrap the <% yield %> in pagination, so each page from the controllers/views will be paginated. The application view will hold the player and every page will paginate. This is my view, would it work?
2. Websockets. I was recently introduced to this technology so I would simply like to ask you if it's a reliable way. I'm impressed by the extremely low latency which would be great for streaming.

I've seen many posts on this subjects with very few useful and detailed answers.
Thanks.

Comment: It is great that you are ambitious to write something interesting. However, I think the questions are very broad, and your ideas at too early a stage for others to understand or answer well. You may like to consider coding up a prototype using one of your ideas, and then you could ask specific questions about that, e.g. "I have set up streaming of a single audio file like this - how could I make it play these other files in sequence. . ."

Comment: My bad, by "continuous music streaming" I meant uninterrupted during page changes. Users should be able to browse each page in the website without the music stopping. I'm asking now since it will be the core challenge and I want to start right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I was looking for: 
`gem 'rails-ajax`.

it is a WONDERFUL solution which makes an Ajax call to the `<%= yield %>` on each page request (so it basically only reloads the yield, not the whole page). You don't really have to change much of your code. This way my music player does not get interrupted on page loads.